# Magento 2.3 Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

Error: do not display images in product detail—Magento cloud
[image]

bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Error:

Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG in /app/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 449

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: it worked for me:

Steps:

1. Go to media: # cd pub/media
2. Execute:  # find . -iname '*.png' -execdir convert {} -interlace none {} ;
   [image]
3. Go to root:  # cd ../../
4. Execute: # bin/magento catalog:images:resize

   [image]